# Replace checkout Username label name with Astra theme in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, field, checkout

I would like to change the text that is set as default "Username or Email Address" with a PHP snippet to "Correo". I tried different ways but haven't got success.

I tried this way, but it doesn't take any effect.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'woocommerce_checkout_fields');

function woocommerce_checkout_fields($fields) {

    $fields['account']['account_username']['Usuario'] = __( 'Username', 'woocommerce' );
    $fields['account']['account_username']['Correo'] = __( 'Account username', 'woocommerce' );

    return $fields;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To change the label name of the checkout account username, try the following:

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'customize_checkout_fields', 99999, 1 );
function customize_checkout_fields($fields) {
    $fields['account']['account_username']['label'] = __( 'Correo', 'woocommerce' );
    $fields['account']['account_username']['placeholder'] = __( 'Correo', 'woocommerce' );

    return $fields;
}
```

You will get:

[image]

---

Or maybe you want to change the billing email to 'Correo' et the username to 'Usuario':

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'customize_checkout_fields', 99999, 1 );
function customize_checkout_fields($fields) {
    $fields['billing']['billing_email']['label'] = __( 'Correo', 'woocommerce' );
    $fields['billing']['billing_email']['placeholder'] = __( 'Correo', 'woocommerce' );

    $fields['account']['account_username']['label'] = __( 'Usuario', 'woocommerce' );
    $fields['account']['account_username']['placeholder'] = __( 'Usuario', 'woocommerce' );

    return $fields;
}
```

You will get something like:

[image]

Comment: it doesn´t take effect as well, what i guess is that, this field ins´t part of Checkout field, is kinda an access to your acount, i´ll share with you my page, and will you see what i refer " https://looch.com.pe/ " just add a ramdom item to the cart and press "finalizar compra" i will appreciatte your help

Comment: I have make an update with an addition and some screenshots that show how it works (I am using Storefront theme). Maybe, your theme may have some related customizations that are prioritized and doesn't allow other customizations in the default WooCommerce way. In that case, you will have to open a ticket in your theme support section.